# In NumPy, how do I sort a 2d array in a given by a given axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, python-3.8

I have a 1d numpy array which I reshape into a 2d array. I can easily sort the 1d array in desc order:

```
import random
import numpy as np


arr = np.array(random.sample(range(0, 1000), 10))

print('Random array:\n', arr)
>>>  [187 161 609 448  63  56 611 795 482 179]

score_indexes = (-arr).argsort()

print('Sorted desc:\n', arr[score_indexes])
>>>  [795 611 609 482 448 187 179 161  63  56]
```

I then will reshape that into a 2d array:

```
grouped_arr = arr.reshape((2, 5))

print(grouped_arr)

print('Members divided in two groups:\n', grouped_arr)

>>> [[187 161 609 448  63]
 [ 56 611 795 482 179]]
```

I would like each of the rows above to be sorted in desc order, so that I end up with this:

```
# [[ 609 448 187 161 63 ]
# [ 795 611 482 179 56 ]]
```

How can this be done?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: `grouped_arr[:,::-1].sort()`?

Comment: You can use `np.sort` and set the axis parameter to 0 or 1. For example `np.sort(data, axis=1).` [Documentation for reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)